# on windows 10, how to make sites use only ipv6, and block ipv4

Tags: windows-10, home-networking, ipv6, ipv4, network-protocols

sites say that blocking ipv4 is at os level and not browser level

when you go to sites, use only ipv6

steps?

Comment: uncheck IPv4 on your NIC, but you'll want to be sure your infrastructure is set up for IPv6 only.

Comment: whats 'nic'? web browser is already setup for ipv6 by whoever makes it, chrome made by google. what's 'infrastructure'? it's just w/e web browser you use, they set it up. everyone uses ipv6

Comment: @liststeps - Your network adapter

Comment: you could achieve this by uncheck IPv4 on corresponded network adapter.

Answer (score 2):

- Press the Windows key + R, you will see the "Run..." dialog.
- Enter `ncpa.cpl` and press Enter.

[image]

- You'll see all your network adapters.  Find the one you are using.  Usually it will say "Local Area Connection" or "Ethernet."  Ignore any hotspot adapters, and if you have both a wired and Wifi connection up, disable the Wifi for now.
- Right click the network adapter you are using and select Properties.

[image]

[image]

- Uncheck "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)"
- Click OK.
- IPv4 is now disabled.  Recheck it later to re-enable.

Comment: Beware that some things will stop working (some websites, POP mail, etc.) From [@Spiff's comment elsewhere](https://superuser.com/a/1510831/133285) "There are still lots of IPv4-only sites and services today. The Internet is not usable without access to IPv4-only sites. "